# Open file dialog and select a file using WPF controls and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, openfiledialog

I have a `TextBox` named `textbox1` and a `Button` named `button1`.
When I click on `button1` I want to browse my files to search only for image files (type jpg, png, bmp...).
And when I select an image file and click Ok in the file dialog I want the file directory to be written in the `textbox1.text` like this:

```
textbox1.Text = "C:\myfolder\myimage.jpg"
```

Comment: I am the author of [tinyfiledialogs](http://tinyfiledialogs.sourceforge.net). It has bindings  for C# (there is a cs example file that shows how to use it).

Answer (score 477, accepted):

Something like that should be what you need:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create OpenFileDialog 
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
    dlg.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";

    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document 
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        textBox1.Text = filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: if (result.HasValue && result.Value) instead of if (result == true)

Comment: @efles what is the value your way provides over the official sample code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx ?

Comment: @eflles The sample is technically correct. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx: *When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to false except for != (not equal).* However I suppose it could be argued whether this is an exploitation of this technicality (I personally think it's OK in this case).

Answer (score 25):

```
var ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog() {Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif"}; 
var result = ofd.ShowDialog();
if (result == false) return;
textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenFileDialog class.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
fileDialog.Title = "Select image file(s)...";
fileDialog.Multiselect = true; // Set to false or never mention this line for single file select

var success = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
if (success == true)
{
    var paths = fileDialog.FileNames;        // Use fileDialog.FileName for a single file - no 's' at the end
    var fileNames = fileDialog.SafeFileNames; // Use fileDialog.SafeFileName for a single file - no 's' at the end
}
```

> References: [How to open a common dialog box | Microsoft .Net 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/how-to-open-common-system-dialog-box?view=netdesktop-8.0)