# Browse button on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

In a WPF application, by using c#, I want users to be able to import their data to grid view. So do i need a browse button or something?

If yes how can I do that?

Comment: check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10315283/161222

Comment: Ohhhhmmmm...my glass ball says it's broken. From where shall the user be able to import the data? From file, clipboard... What do you mean by _browse button_?

Comment: what type of file are you trying to import? You'll need to parse through the data in order to fill your datagrid, there is no magic import functionality in a datagrid, you need to implement it yourself. The browse button is the easy part.

Comment: Add a button to the window in an appropriate place: `<Button>Browse</Button>`. Honestly, you should at least include what you are trying to do, where you have problems and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The below code helps you to display the browse button

```
<TextBox Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,10,0,0" Name="FileNameTextBox"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="393" />
        <Button Content="Browse" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="405,10,0,0"
                Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" Click="button1_Click" />


// Create OpenFileDialog
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();          

// Set filter for file extension and default file extension
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

// Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
if (result == true)
{
    // Open document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
    FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But how can i make the selected file's data import to my own WPF