# Dinamically generate a button to open file dialog and select a file using WPF controls and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Basically I'm making a program that allows you to add to a stackpanel another stackpanel with several horizontally aligned textboxes with the press of a button. So far, everything is working as intented. Here's my code so far ,Stacker is the name of the parent stackpanel and it starts off empty:

```
    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stacker.Children.Add(NewXD(Stacker.Children.Count + 1));
    }
    public System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel NewXD(int XD)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel NewP = new StackPanel();
        NewP.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox HAHA = new TextBox();
        HAHA.Name = "question" + XD.ToString();
        //HAHA.Text = HAHA.Height.ToString()+" "+HAHA.Width.ToString();
        HAHA.Height = Double.NaN;
        HAHA.Width = 120;
        HAHA.FontSize=20;
        NewP.Children.Add(HAHA);

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.TextBox newBox = new TextBox();

            newBox.Name = "answer"+XD.ToString()+"_"+i.ToString();
            newBox.Height = Double.NaN;
            newBox.Width = 120;

            NewP.Children.Add(newBox);
        }
        System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox correct = new ComboBox();
        correct.Name = "correct" + XD.ToString();
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem newItem = new ComboBoxItem();
            newItem.Name = "ans" + XD.ToString() + "_" + i.ToString();
            newItem.Content = i.ToString();
            correct.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
        NewP.Children.Add(correct);
            return NewP;
    }
```

I apologize for the lack of seriousness in some of my code.

Now, what I need to do is for the child stackpanels to also contain independent file pickers that work like the one sampled in this thread: [Open file dialog and select a file using WPF controls and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315188/open-file-dialog-and-select-a-file-using-wpf-controls-and-c-sharp)

What I don't know how to perform is that each of these generated buttons have the same basic funcion but are linked with each of their corresponding textbox.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: As I was writing this it occured to me that perhaps I could use the help of the child stackpanel's array-like properties to choose the corresponding textbox, because the file selector's textbox and button will always be the last two items in the stackpanel, but I'm not very sure how to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

For functionality you can create an `EventHandler` that will be assigned to each button. Your event handler will then open `File Dialog`...

Buttons have `Tag` property which you could use to identify your `TextBoxes`, or you could derive from `Button` class and add *AssociatedTextBox* property for example.