# Adding and deleting files from my playlist. (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have tried OpenFileDialog but I just can not do it right. What should be my C# code that would allow me to add and remove files from my playlist?

Comment: don't forget accept my answer thank you ;-)

Comment: you didnt accept my answer and i get downed  :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for your problem in wpf for open file dialog whatch thi link [Open file dialog and select a file using WPF controls and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315188/open-file-dialog-and-select-a-file-using-wpf-controls-and-c-sharp)

and for add and remove items by code watch this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/643/how-to-add-and-remove-items-in-a-wpf-listbox.aspx